# use the output of rename to make directory wo renaming the files

Tags: pipe, rename, mkdir

I have a directory with multiple files that they all end as "_1.fastq.gz" or "_2.fastq.gz"

```
ERR3258060_1.fastq.gz  
ERR3258060_2.fastq.gz  
ERR3258861_1.fastq.gz  
ERR3258861_2.fastq.gz
```

What I want to do (in a first step) is take all the files that end in _1.fastq.gz keep the first 10 characters of the filename (the ERR32.....) and make a directory with that

therefore the directories would look like
ERR3258060
ERR3258861

using bash I have so far tried the following

```
for f in *_1.fastq.gz
do
echo $f | rename -n 's/_1.fastq.gz//' * | mkdir
done
```

The command produces the filename the way i want it but mkdir will not take the output of the rename, it will simply say "missing operand"
how can I make mkdir take the result of the previous command?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `rename`. You can just use `sed`.
In the first step, you create the directory name and then use it in `mkdir`.

```
for f in *_1.fastq.gz
do
    dir=$(echo $f | sed 's/_1.fastq.gz//')
    mkdir $dir
done
```